# Autoloading failed to define function calc-dispatch

Tags: emacs

I'm not sure how it happened, but calc no longer works.  Whenever I try to start it, I get:

> Autoloading failed to define function calc-dispatch

It was working fine last week and I am using the built-in calc, so I have no idea what changed to prevent it from working.  I ran `lgrep` on a copy of the `calc` directory searching for `calc-dispatch` and it found calc-dispatch just fine. Could my .elc files have gotten corrupted?

When I tried to recompile them, I got stuff like:

> calc-fin.el:29:1:Error: Required feature `calc' was not provided

Comment: That sounds a little like Emacs' own lisp directories are no longer in its `load-path`. But I'd be surprised if *anything* was working if that were the case, unless the filesystem has changed while Emacs was running? I assume this is happening when starting a new instance of Emacs, though? I guess you should check for permissions issues on the calc* files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue was that calc's default `calc-settings-file` is called `calc.el` by default.  When I saved my customizations, the `calc.el` in my `.emacs.d` directory clobbered the `calc.el` in `/usr/share/emacs/lisp/calc/` because I have `.emacs.d` in my load path.  Transfering the contents of that file to my `init.el` and deleting it fixed the issue.  I emailed the maintainer about the issue and received a very prompt and thurough response explaining the problem.

Comment: Although it wouldn't have made a difference in this case, take `~/.emacs.d` out of your `load-path` if you've not already done so (Emacs devs have stated that it's a bad idea), and use a sub-directory instead.

Comment: I use `my-` as a prefix for all of my custom lisp (whether files, functions, or variables) in order to avoid name-space clashes. I'd recommend doing something similar.